# Reset form but set a single field to a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a reset button which currently clears an entire VBA form I've created. I would like it however to clear the entire form and set the value of a drop down called **cbo_deptCode** to "CO - Computer Science". How would I go about accomplishing this?

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub btn_Reset_Click()

    ' Reset form
    Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctl.Text = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
                ctl.Value = False
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                ctl.ListIndex = -1
        End Select
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add:

```
cbo_deptCode.Value = "CO - Computer Science"
```

After your loop?

Comment: I typed in `cbo_deptCode = "CO - Computer Science"` instead it works now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What are the specific properties for the combobox? do you have MatchEntry set to true, if so, is that text in the list? Do you have it set to List Only mode? Do you have any code in the change event that may be triggering?

Comment: The text is available in the list. MatchEntry is set to true and it is set to ListOnly mode.

Comment: Ah right, so `CO - Computer Sci` wasn't in the list, but  `CO - Computer Science` was. `cbo_deptCode.Value = "CO - Computer Science"` should work in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm still getting to grips with VBA

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18222/discussion-between-methuselah-and-kyle)